# How steering wheel with force feedback read and send data amount windows using USB HID

Tags: usb, driver, hid

How steering  wheel with force feedback read and send data amount windows using USB HID?
Is there any sample project of driver for steering wheel to communicate with PC?
Or detailed docs about develop a firmware on steering wheel device?
I have viewed pid.pdf but have no idea how to do detailly.
Thanks!